# Arraylist and Iteration

Tags: java, excel

I have an Excel File with Values in the Ranges C17:C40, D17:D40 and E17:E40.
Now I read with Apache Poi the first Range with a for each loop. My Problem is I want to include a Code something like this:

If C17 is empty go to the next range (in this case D17) and check if D17 ist empty. If not read every Cell from the List and put it into a new Array list.

I hope some of you understand me. Here is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

     public static ArrayList<String> ForEachLoop() throws EncryptedDocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
           Workbook readWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(FileChooser.FileChoose()) );
           Sheet sheet = readWorkbook.getSheetAt(4);
           DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

           String cellValue = null;





           for (int i = 16; i < 40; i++) {  //Statt 20 soll hier 40

               Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
               if(row == null) {

                   continue;
               }
               for (int j = 2; j < 4; j++) {
                   Cell cell = row.getCell(j);

                   list.add(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                   if(cell == null) {

                       continue;
                   }
                  // cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                  // System.out.print(cellValue + "\n");
               }
           }
        return list;

     }
```

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Please read [ask] and [example].

Comment: You are on the right track, however put the if (cell == null) before you operate on the cell, or you will get NullPointerExceptions, like from this line list.add(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));